# Как назвать явление «главенизации»?

Tags: выбор-слов, семантика, синонимы, существительные, лексикология

Как называется явление, когда что-либо «главенизируется» (ставится во главу, на первое место)? Например, ценность существования детей у человека или материальное богатство. «Генерализация» не подходит? Только «абсолютизация», других вариантов нет?

Comment: Попробуйте "приоритизацию", хотя в широком смысле это слово означет  только "расстановку приоритетов" и может потребовать уточнений. Слова "главенизация" нет и воспринимается оно странно.

Comment: Варианты есть, но контекста нужно больше. Скажем, с негативным оттенком (о материальном богатстве, например) *может* подойти [идолизация](https://gallicismes.academic.ru/15720/идолизация), *идолизирование*. Но это достаточно редкие слова, и легко путаются с *идеализацией*, особенно на слух. Иными словами - наверное, нет одного слова на все случаи жизни, но найдутся слова для конкретного контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически эту вашу "главенизацию" можно счесть за окказионализм, то есть в авторском тексте его появление уместно при наличии разъяснения: что вы имеете в виду под этим термином. Что касается синонимов, очень многое зависит от контекста. Мне кажется, в ряде случаев "главенизацию" можно заменить на "возвышение" или "превознесение" (сравните, мысленно заменив в примерах из "Нацкорпуса", приведённых в конце данного ответа).

**ВОЗВЫШЕНИЕ (ВОЗВЫШАТЬ)** — поднять, сделать более высоким; придать кому-либо, чему-либо более высокое общественное положение или значение (см. [Карту слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

**ПРЕВОЗНЕСЕНИЕ (ПРЕВОЗНОСИТЬ)** — давать очень высокую оценку кому-либо, чему-либо; возвеличивать, восхвалять (см. [Карту слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

*Таким образом, религиозно-просветительная деятельность Братства святого благоверного великого князя Александра Невского была направлена, с одной стороны, на **возвышение** религиозно-нравственного развития народа через пастырские внебогослужеб-ные собеседования и чтения и, с другой, на предохранение православных от увлечения и совращения в сектантство, и к обращению заблудших. [М. Я. Федотова. Миссионерская деятельность во Владимирской епархии в последней трети XIX -- начале XX века // «Актуальные вопросы современной науки», 2018]*

*Эту мысль можно продолжить: искусственное **возвышение** одного народа в рамках какой-либо страны приводит к страданиям других. [А. В. Суперанская. Человек ― фамилия ― национальность // «Наука и жизнь», 2009]*

*Опыт показывает, что **превознесение** происходящего на высоком уровне (съездов и тому подобного) ― своего рода норма, и в этом смысле новизны никакой нет. [И. А. Дедков. Дневник (1986)]*

*Затем последовала реакция: Темные Века, **превознесение** религии и отвергание, подавление сексуальности. [И. А. Ефремов. Час быка (1968-1969)]*

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил **возвеличивание**.